# Set up the limits and evaluate $\iiint ydv$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, volume

Set up the limits and evaluate the integral.

$$\displaystyle\iiint ydv$$
$$G$$

G is the region enclosed by the plane $z = y$, $xy-plane$ and the surface $y = 1 - x^2$

I need help finding the limits of integration. I have this so far, but I don't think it is correct.

$$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} y\;dz\;dy\;dx$$

Comment: I think it's set up correctly because if you take antiderivative in terms of dz you would have yz and if you evaluate it from $F(y) - F(0)$ you would have $yy$ or $y^2$. then you take the antiderivative in terms of $y$ and you'll have $\frac{y^3}{3}$. Evaluate from $F(1-x^2) -F(0) $ and you'll have x terms remaining. Now take the antiderivative in terms of dx and evaluate from $F(1)-F(0)$

If the intergral was set up incorrectly, you wouldn't be able to take the antiderivative of whatever the letter was again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} y\;dz\;dy\;dx$

Taking the antiderivative in terms of $dz$, we have

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} yz\;dy\;dx$

Now, evaluate from $F(y) -f(0)$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} yy\;dy\;dx$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} y^2\;dy\;dx$

Taking the antiderivative in terms of $dy$, we have

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{y^3}{3}\;dx$

Now, evaluate from $F(1-x^2) -f(0)$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{(1-x^2)^3}{3}\;dx$

We need to expand first

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{-x^6+3x^4-3x^2+1}{3}\;dx$

and simplify

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{-x^6}{3}+x^4-x^2+\frac{1}{3}\;dx$

Taking the antiderivative in terms of $dx$, we have

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{-x^7}{21}+\frac{x^5}{5}-\frac{x^3}{3}+\frac{x}{3}$

Evaluate from $f(1) -f(0)$

$\displaystyle\int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1 - x^2}\int_{0}^{y} \frac{-1}{21}+\frac{1}{5}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{3}$

The final answer is $\frac{16}{105}$